# Given a metric space $(X,d)$, the set $X$ and $\varnothing$ are both open and closed in $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

When I started learning about metric spaces, I came across the following lemma: Given a metric space (X,d), the set X and ∅ are both open and closed in X.

I know there are very similar questions asked here, and I looked at them. However, there is something that I don't understand about it.

If X is a closed set, how can X be a open in X? By definition, if X is open in X, we can always find an open ball such that for all ε>0 there is an element x∈Χ for all x (B(x,ε)). But since X is closed, there would be contradiction at both endpoints in X, which leads to the fact that we can't find an open ball at endpoints of X if X is closed.

Since I still haven't understood this after looking at similar questions asked here, I am sure that there is some fundamental things that I'm missing or misunderstanding. If someone can help me understand what seems to be lacking in my understanding, it would be really helpful.

Comment: There are lots of examples of sets which are both open and closed. Start with a simple example like: $X=\{0,1\}$ with usual metric. Show that $\{0\}$ is open and closed.

Comment: Do you know that metric spaces are also [topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_category_of_topological_spaces)? In particular $(X,\mathcal{T})$. A set $A\subseteq X$ is called closed, when $X\setminus A$ is open, that is $X\setminus A\in\mathcal{T}$. But $X,\varnothing\in\mathcal{T}$ by definition of $\mathcal{T}$. So $X,\varnothing$ are closed and open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But since X is closed, there would be contradiction at both endpoints in X,

What's an endpoint of $X$? There is no such thing in general metric spaces. I think you consider something like $X=[0,1]$ with the Euclidean distance and you consider open balls around $0$. But in this space, for example $B(0,\frac{1}{2})=[0,\frac{1}{2})$. Or $B(0,2)=[0,1]$. Note that here our universe is $[0,1]$, there is no real line $\mathbb{R}$.

So I think that what actually confuses you is that the term "open" and "closed" applied to intervals **is not** the same as "open" and "closed" applied to subsets of a metric space. These may or may not coincide, depending on $X$.

Here's how you typically define open and closed in a metric space:

> **Open:** A subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is open if and only if for any $x\in A$ there is $\epsilon>0$ such that the open ball $B(x,\epsilon)=\{y\in X\ |\ d(y,x)<\epsilon\}$ is fully contained in $A$.
>
> **Closed:** A subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is closed if and only if given a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $x_i\in A$ for all $i$ and such that $(x_n)$ converges to some $x\in X$ we actually have that $x\in A$.

Then you have a theorem that a subset $A\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $X\backslash A$ is open. And vice versa: $A\subseteq X$ is open if and only if $X\backslash A$ is closed.

But there still can be subsets that are both open and closed at the same time. So lets consider $A=X$.

**Open:** Let $x\in A$. Does there exists an open ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ fully contained in $A$? Of course, any ball is fully contained in $A$, since $A=X$.

**Closed:** Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $A$ convergent to some $x\in X$. Does it imply that $x\in A$? Of course, this is trivially true, since $A=X$.

Comment: In a topological space (X,T) the empty set and X are both members of T,  by definition of a topology. "Open" by definition means "belongs to T."So their complements are also members of T. The definition of "closed" is "complement belongs to T." So a set is closed iff its complement is open and open iff its complement is closed.  The topological space (X,T) is defined to be "connected" if X and the empty set are the only sets which are both open and closed. By definition of a metric, a metric space is a topological space. Just check both sets of axioms. Don't forget vacuous implication.

Comment: @P.Lawrence How exactly a metric space is a topological space "by definition"? It is not. It is not even close. You have to define how a metric spaces induces a topology, just like I did in my post, and prove that in fact it is a topology. Moreover different metric spaces can induce same topology. Metric spaces **are not** special cases of topological spaces. For example a complete and non-complete metric space can induce the same topology. While clearly the concept of being complete is important in analysis. So metrics and topologies are different beasts.

Comment: :Sorry, lack of space in '"omments" made my "by definition" unclear. There is a definition of "open" and "closed" in a general topological space. You are right that the definition of a metric space does not use the words "open" or "closed" or "topology" and that there are many topologies possible on a metric space. However, with the ususual topologyon a metric space and with the usual definition of "open" and "cl0sed" for a metric space, the  sets tat are "open" and "closed" in the metric-space meaning are "open" and "closed" in the topological sense of the words.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that we are dealing with a topological space, so view the open and closed subset with respect to the conditions ... Closed under finite intersection and arbitrary union.